# Aperiodic To Periodic Time series

Tags: r, datetime, interpolation

I am trying implement interpolating a time series to make it periodic. I have inserted the data below.

```
DateTime    x
7/1/2010 0:03   12.7
7/1/2010 0:08   12.7
7/1/2010 0:13   12.7
7/1/2010 0:18   12.5
7/1/2010 0:23   12.5
7/1/2010 0:28   12.4
7/1/2010 0:33   12.5
7/1/2010 0:38   12.5
7/1/2010 0:43   12.4
7/1/2010 0:48   12.4
7/1/2010 0:53   12.4
7/1/2010 0:58   12.4
7/1/2010 1:03   12.2
7/1/2010 1:08   12.2
7/1/2010 1:13   12.2
7/1/2010 1:18   12.2
7/1/2010 1:23   12.2
7/1/2010 1:28   12.2
7/1/2010 1:33   12.2
```

One hour data.

```
7/1/2010 00:00:00   12.508
7/1/2010 00:00:00   12.2
```

I tried Cublic spline interpolation in SAS guide. It gave a very good results. Trying implement something similar in R.

Comment: do you want to interpolate or just to aggregate to get hourly data?

Comment: Wouldn't interpolation provide much accurate results?  I do not know how many instance of data I would receive every hour. I am not sure which would be better method.